# The equivalence of hypothesis testing and confidence intervals in the test of proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, proportion

Why, in this case, is the test using a confidence interval not equivalent to the test using hypothesis testing, and is it?

Hypothesis testing for

$H_0: \pi = \pi_0$

$H_1: \pi\neq\pi_0$

A single trial has a Bernoulli distribution with mean $\pi$ and variance $\pi(1-\pi)$. According to the central limit theorem, the average of $n$ trials will have (approximately) mean $\pi$ and variance $\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}n$. Therefore,

$U_1 = \frac{\hat \pi -\pi}{\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}$ is from $\mathcal N(0;1)$

If $H_0$ is true, $\pi = \pi_0$, so if $H_0$ is true,

$U_2 = \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$ is from $\mathcal N(0;1)$.

So we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> U_2$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< U_2$).

In other words, we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$).

On the contrary, testing according to confidence intervals:

The confidence interval is

$\left[\hat\pi - u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}};\hat\pi + u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}\right]$

We reject $H_0$ iff ($\pi_0< \hat\pi - u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$ or $\pi_0> \hat\pi + u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$).

In other words, we reject $H_0$ iff ($\pi_0-\hat\pi < - u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$ or $\pi_0-\hat {\pi} >  u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$).

Rewriting the parenthesis:

($\hat\pi -\pi_0 > u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$ or $\hat {\pi} -\pi_0 < -u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$)

($\hat\pi -\pi_0 > u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$ or $\hat {\pi} -\pi_0 < u_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}$)

($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$)

The difference:

When using hypothesis testing, we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$).

On the contrary, when using the confidence interval, we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$).

Is the difference caused by replacing $\pi$ with $\hat\pi$ while constructing the confidence interval, making it just an approximate confidence interval? Or by something else?

(There are other questions on the site about the equivalence between confidence intervals and hypothesis testing, but none of them helped me with this.)

Comment: No they are the same tests (confidence interval is approximate of course because this is a large sample test). In fact the [Wald CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval) is derived from this test itself (see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448233/the-derivation-of-the-wald-interval).

Comment: @StubbornAtom They're not the same, because when we do hypothesis testing, we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{n}}$), but when we use the confidence interval, we reject $H_0$ iff ($u_\frac{\alpha}{2}> \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$ or $u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}< \frac{\hat \pi -\pi_0}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}$). I guess that instead of asking if they're the same, I only should've asked what's the difference caused by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,  if you use the value of the parameter under the null hypothesis in the standard error calculation in U2, then you are performing the score test. If you had instead produced a test statistic using the sample proportion instead in the standard error, you'd be performing the Wald test and you'd have consistency with rejecting based on the Wald confidence interval in your post. Both tests are valid asymptotic tests, but the score test has better properties in this case.

http://ocw.jhsph.edu/courses/MethodsInBiostatisticsII/PDFs/lecture18.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but I can derive the confidence interval that I used, simply from using the assumption that $U_1 = \frac{\hat \pi -\pi}{\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}$ is from $\mathcal N(0;1)$. And yet I end up with a different rejection condition than in case of hypothesis testing. I suppose that what I'm really interested in is what's the difference caused by (since I'm starting with the same assumption in both cases). My guess was that it's caused by us replacing $\pi$ with $\hat\pi$ when deriving the confidence interval. Is that right?

Comment: @GoldenGleam You're not starting with the same assumption. The confidence interval is derived from the assumption that $\frac{\hat \pi -\pi}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}\sim N(0,1)$ This comes from central limit theorem and Slutsky. This is true for any value of $\pi$. The assumption that $U_2 \sim N(0,1)$ is only true if $\pi=\pi_0$, and is only based on CLT.

Comment: (Part 1) I derive the confidence interval from $U_1=\frac{\hat \pi -\pi}{\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}} \sim \mathcal N(0;1)$, therefore $P(u_\frac{\alpha}2 < \frac{\hat\pi - \pi}{\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}n} < u_{1-\frac\alpha 2})=95\%$. Therefore, $P(\hat\pi-u_{1-\frac{\alpha}2}\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}n<\pi<\hat\pi + u_{1-\frac{\alpha}2}\sqrt\frac{\pi(1-\pi}n)$. Afterwards I replace $\pi$ with $\hat\pi$ twice to obtain the confidence interval $\left[\hat\pi - u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}};\hat\pi + u_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{\pi})\hat{\pi}}{n}}\right]$.

Comment: @GoldenGleam.  You can't derive a confidence interval in that manner from $U_1$.  You get stuck and then decide to replace because you got stuck is not a principled approach, and you are providing no justification regarding why you can make that substitution at that point.  I gave you the technically correct way of constructing the interval, and it replaces it in step 1 using slutsky to demonstrate that after replacing, you still have $N(0,1)$.

Comment: (Part 2) Thanks, but that was just a part one. I thought it would be only an approximate confidence interval, since $\hat \pi$ is usually close to $\pi$. But now I understand that it's a real confidence interval, because $U = \frac{\hat \pi -\pi}{\sqrt\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ too. So the actual reason I got a different result is that my confidence interval belongs to a different random variable than the hypothesis testing (namely, $U$ instead of $U_1$). Is that right?

Comment: (So if I based hypothesis testing on $U$, they would be equivalent. Or, alternatively, if I based my confidence interval on $U_1$, they would be equivalent too. Right?)

Comment: If you use $U$ to hypothesis test and construct the interval, they would be equivalent.  The score test is based on $U_2$, not $U$.  $U\sim N(0,1)$ regardless of $\pi$, but $U_2 \sim N(0,1)$ only if $H_0$ is true, which is the whole point of a hypothesis test: make an assumption about $\pi$, determine the distribution of a test statistic if that assumption is true, then look for evidence that something unusual happened under that assumption.

Comment: "If you use $U$ to hypothesis test and construct the interval, they would be equivalent." - thanks. (I knew the rest of your comment, but thanks for explaining more and not less.) I still don't 100% know if using $U_1$ to both do a hypothesis test and construct the interval would be equivalent, but I'm mostly to almost completely sure that it would, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Both hypothesis tests start from $U_1$. You need a hypothesized value for $\pi =\pi_0$, then you have to decide whether to use $\pi_0$in the standard error ($U_2$) or estimate the standard error with $\hat{\pi} $ ($U$).

Comment: I was drawing a distinction between a hypothesis test for which I use the random variable $U_1$, and a hypothesis test for which I use $U$. Those are two different hypothesis tests, because they have different conditions for rejecting $H_0$.

Comment: I'm trying to explain to you that you can't actually calculate a value for $U_1$ without knowing the value hypothesized value of $\pi$, which is the entire point of a hypothesis test.

Comment: I know that, thanks. My second half of the question was about whether the confidence interval constructed from $U_1$ would be equivalent to the hypothesis test constructed from $U_1$ (which is the same as a hypothesis test constructed from $U_2$, but not the same as a hypothesis test constructed from $U$). But I'd already deduced that the answer is yes, so it's fine.

Comment: I see. The score test has an equivalent confidence interval called the Wilson score interval. The Wald test has an equivalent interval called the Wald interval. The two confidence intervals will never be the same.