# Computing p-value vs. constructing confidence interval from sample for proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value, proportion

Let's say D is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\mu = 0.6$ and we want to test whether or not $\mu=0.5$. So,

Null hypothesis: $\mu = 0.5$

Alt hypothesis: $\mu \neq 0.5$.

Suppose we have a sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n \sim D$ for large $n$. Now, my understanding is there are two ways to do the hypothesis test. One approach is to assume the null hypothesis is correct and calculate the probability of seeing $\bar{X}_n$. If the null is correct, then we expect the distribution for the sample mean to be

$$N(0.5, (0.5*0.5)/n)$$

Then we can calculate the p-value. However, equivalently we can construct a confidence interval from our sample and reject the null hypothesis if 0.5 is not in our constructed range.

$$N(\hat{p}, \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n)$$

My confusion is, are these two methods really equivalent? Because the variance of the normal distribution would be smaller for the second approach, isn't it possible that you could reject the null hypothesis in the second approach, but fail to reject the null hypothesis in the first approach? Any intuitive explanation for why they are equivalent?

Comment: Your sense of "equivalent" is a narrow one, because it focuses only on performance under the null (that is, the test *size*).  An important aspect of performance is how the test does when the null is false: its *power.*  Clearly these tests aren't anywhere near the same when it comes to the power to detect extreme departures from the null, because in those cases $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ is likely to be smaller than $(1/2)^2.$  So maybe you would find it more useful to study the entire *risk function* of each test and compare them.

Comment: It's not true that a test is based on only "calculating the probability of seeing $\bar X_n$". It is always based on the probability of "what was observed plus anything that is even less likely under the null hypothesis". This implies that there is a difference between one-sided and two-sided tests, and any approach to construct tests based on standard confidence intervals will correspond to two-sided tests, not one-sided ones (unless one uses confidence intervals ranging to (minus) infinity).

Comment: A confidence interval based on normal approximation for the Bernoulli where $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ (by the way $\hat p=\bar X_n$) is plugged in for the variance estimator involves two approximations (one by the Central Limit Theorem, the other by variance estimation) and is therefore *not* equivalent to a test that does not involve variance estimation. (There are confidence intervals for the Bernoulli that don't estimate the variance either though.)

Comment: Correction to my first comment: "confidence intervals ranging to (minus) infinity" should have said "ranging to the border of the parameter space", which here obviously is 0 or 1, not infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I guess my understanding is wrong. You can reject the null under one approach but not the other. Which version is "correct" then (which should one use in a hypothesis test)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The equivalence of hypothesis testing and confidence intervals in the test of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411587/the-equivalence-of-hypothesis-testing-and-confidence-intervals-in-the-test-of-pr)

Answer (score 6):

> My confusion is, are these two methods really equivalent?

No the methods are indeed not equivalent.

Note that there are also many different ways to construct the confidence intervals (and different ways to express hypothesis tests). The use of the parameter estimate $\hat{p}$ in the expression $N(\hat{p}, \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n)$ is a simplification and does not give an exact interval. The justification is that $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ and $p(1-p)$ do not differ much when the sample size is large enough.

See more on the [Wikipedia page about different ways to construct confidence intervals for the binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

- The interval based on $N(\hat{p}, \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n)$ corresponds to the Wald interval. (the hypothesis test that corresponds to this interval is the [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test))
- The expression $N(0.5, (0.5*0.5)/n)$ is more related to the Wilson score interval.

See also [Confidence interval / p-value duality: don't they use different distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561578/) in which the examples in the answer by Demetri Pananos and in some of the comments relate to the binomial proportion.

Comment: Are there also different ways to construct test statistics? (Wald test, score test, likelihood ratio test, etc.)

Comment: @Alexis, yes there are also different ways to construct the tests. The Wald test for the hypothesis test p=0.5 would not be using the variance based on p=0.5, but instead based on the observed estimate $\hat{p}$.

Comment: So why the first sentence of your second paragraph? It seems to imply that every CI cannot be inverted into a corresponding test statistic. Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

A confidence interval based on normal approximation for the Bernoulli where $\hat p(1−\hat p)$ (by the way $\hat p=\bar X_n$) is plugged in for the variance estimator involves two approximations (one by the Central Limit Theorem, the other by variance estimation) and is therefore *not* equivalent to a test that does not involve variance estimation.

There are confidence intervals for the Bernoulli that don't estimate the variance either though, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval.
I believe that the Wilson score interval explained there will, by checking whether 0.5 is in it, give you a test equivalent to the one you discuss, i.e., with normal approximation but without estimating the variance (assuming that the test is two-sided).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $n = 100$ independent observations $X_i$
from a Bernoulli distribution with Success probability $p.$
Then $$T_{100} = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p).$$

Suppose you want to test $H_0: p = 0.5$ against $H_a: p \ne 0.5$

In particular, you might observe $T = 38$ Successes in $n = 100$ trials.
Then using `binom.test` in R, you get the following results:

```
binom.test(38, 100, .5)

        Exact binomial test

data:  38 and 100
number of successes = 38, number of trials = 100, 
 p-value = 0.02098
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2847675 0.4825393
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                   0.38
```

The P-value of this test is $0.02098 < 0.05 = 5\%.$
so you reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ at the 5% level of significance.

The P-value for this 2-sided test can be computed as
$$P(T \le 38) + P(T \ge 62) = 2P(T \le 38) = 0.02097874,$$ where $T \sim \mathsf{Binom}(100, 0.5).$ Computation in R below.

```
2 * pbinom(38, 100, 0.5) 
[1] 0.02097874
```

The idea is to find the probability of a value as far or farther from
the mean $np = 100(.5) = 50$ as is $38,$ **in either direction.**

If you want to use critical values, then you would reject if
the observed total $T \le 39$ or $T \ge 61.$ Then the size of
the test is $\alpha = 0.352.$ If you tried to use critical
values $40$ and $60$ (instead of 39 and 51), then the size of
the test would be $0.057,$ which exceeds 5%. Because of the
discreteness of the binomial distribution, it is not possible
to test at exactly the 5% level.

```
2*pbinom(39, 100, .5)
[1] 0.0352002
2*pbinom(40, 100, .5)
[1] 0.05688793
```

Also, the confidence interval $(0.285 0.483)$ for $p$ shown in the R output has
very nearly the intended 95% coverage probability for all possible
values of $p.$

In the figure below, the P-value of the test is the sum
of the heights of the vertical black bars outside the vertical blue lines.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
t = 0:100;  PDF = dbinom(t, 100, .5)
hdr = "Null Dist'n BINOM(100, 0.5)"
plot(t, PDF, type="h", lwd = 3, main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = c(38.5, 61.5), col="blue")
```

---

*Notes:* (1) Because $n$ is sufficiently large that $T$ is approximately
normal, then you could use an approximate normal test. With
such a test you can *pretend* to test at the 5% level, but
the standardized binomial statistic $Z = \frac{T - np_0}{\sqrt{np_0(1-p_0)}}$ does not take all of the values implied by $|Z| \ge 1.96.$

For $T = 38,$ the normal test statistic
is $Z = -2.4$ and the P-value is about $0.016 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
t = 38;  n = 100;  p=0.5
z = (t - n*p)/sqrt(n*p*(1-p));  z
[1] -2.4
2 * pnorm(z)
[1] 0.01639507
```

(2) Various statistical programs do the exact test or the
normal approximation, or both. Also, some give one or more
style of confidence interval. Here is output from a recent
release of Minitab software. The first output shown is essentially
the same as for the exact test in R, but displayed differently:

```
Test and CI for One Proportion 

Test of p = 0.5 vs p ≠ 0.5

                                                   Exact
Sample   X    N  Sample p         95% CI         P-Value
1       38  100  0.380000  (0.284767, 0.482539)    0.021
```

Minitab's version of the approximate normal test is shown below; accordingly, it gives a
different P-value $(0.16)$ than for the exact test, but still happens to reject
at the 5% level. Of course, when you have two different tests
it might happen that you reject with one and not with the other. [In particular, if you have $T = 38$ and $n=100.$ then Minitab's exact test will not reject at the 2% level and its approximate normal test will reject at that level.]

```
Test and CI for One Proportion 

Test of p = 0.5 vs p ≠ 0.5

Sample   X    N  Sample p         95% CI         Z-Value  P-Value
1       38  100  0.380000  (0.284866, 0.475134)    -2.40    0.016
```

(3) The two Minitab printouts give slightly different 95% CIs. @SextusEmpiricius provides a link to a Wikipedia
page that shows several styles of CIs in common usage.
It seems that the second Minitab printout gives the Wald
95% CI: With $\hat p = 38/100,$ it is
$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ which
computes to $(0.285,\, 0.475).$

```
p.hat = t/n
CI = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
CI
[1] 0.284866 0.475134
```

The Wald interval is an *asymptotic* interval, which should
be used only for large $n.$ It does not 'invert the test'
and so should not be used as a substitute for the approximate
normal test unless $n$ is very large (my personal rule is
$n \ge 500).$

Various styles of CIs can give remarkably different results
for some sample sizes and totals $T.$ Consequently, if you are
going to use CIs to do tests, you might see frequent
disagreement whether to accept or reject. In particular,
some 'exact' 95% CIs are quite long in order to be sure to give
at least 95% coverage for all possible values of $p.$ These
intervals are less likely to reject $H_0$ at significance level 5%.

Comment: The question is about comparing two tests, so I was disappointed not to find any analysis of the second test here.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @whuber. My impression was that the first answer had already discussed normal tests, so I mentioned the possibility only briefly. May add to this later.

Comment: My sense is the question concerns what test statistic to use "for large $n$:" the one based on a sample estimate of $\hat p$ for the Normal approximation or the one based on the specified value of $p$ under the null hypothesis.  Ultimately this determination is made by comparing the risk curves (that is, actual confidence plus the entire power curve).