Head First Statistics Book: error in hypothesis test?
Chapter 13 in the book Head First Statistics deals with hypothesis testing. Its example is like the below:

A drug (called snorecull) cures snore at a rate, 0.9. Then, one gets
the below results.




cured
not cured




freq
11
4



How do you determine if the drug works?

The books uses just binomial distribution to test the hypothesis like this (in R):
pbinom(11, 15, 0.9) = 0.0555 

Based on the result, the book states that there is no evidence of drug's not working.
My question is: Do we need to use "the logics of distribution of sample proportions (means)" to test the hypothesis?
Accordingly, we know that $P_s$ (sample proportions when sample size is 15) follows:
\begin{align}
Ps &\sim \mathcal{N}(p, pq/n)  \\\\
    p &= .9                    \\\\
    pq/n &= var.ps = 0.006     \\\\
    \sqrt{pq/n} &= se = standard deviation of ps = 0.07745967
\end{align}
Therefore, we need to test like this in R:
pnorm(11/15, p, se) 

which results in a value of 0.01571217.
Am I wrong?
--- added after Arya's comment
Yes, the book offers $np, nq > 5$. Basically the book suggest as follows:
> # the book
> p <- .9
> q <- 1-p
> n <- 100
> cured <- 80
> not.cured <- n-cured
> 
> pbinom(cured, n, p)
[1] 0.001978561
>

What I am thinking is that I should use some sort of sampling distribution idea. So
> # from the distribution X ~ B(n, .9) 
> # we know that proportions of samples 
> # = Ps ~ N(p, pq/n)
> vs.ps <- p*q/n
> sd.ps <- sqrt(p*q/n)
> vs.ps 
[1] 0.09
> sd.ps
[1] 0.03
> # Hence we need to test like this:
> pnorm(0.8, p, sd.ps)
[1] 0.0004290603
> # or the below is the same
> z.sc <- (0.8-p)/sd.ps
> z.sc
[1] -3.333333
> pnorm(z.sc)
[1] 0.0004290603
> 

I hope this makes a sense. And sorry about editing the original question. I am not familiar with using comment with R coding ...

Why are you using a normal distribution? It is a poor approximation to the binomial when $np$ or $nq$ is small. But the binomial distribution is the one you truly want anyway.

There are many different tests that you can perform. Using the binomial distribution, as the book does, is fine https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

I wonder if there isn't already some question about this.

related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566867/

Our popular thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756 provides a good overview of some of the methods available to you and their properties.

The reason is that the text book is using one method, and that you are using another; 2 different methods, 2 differemt answers.
It turns out that there are a very large number of methods to compute a CI of a binomial distribution; it is definitively one of the most studied/published topics in statistics. And there is probably as many opinions about which is "the best" as there are statisticians. For example, see wiki, for a list of (only some) of the methods, or this paper which compares 13 methods, as well as this one, or this one.
And the problem is that, even with this wide range of opinions about the "best method", there is general consensus that the method you used (Wald Interval) is "the worse (e.g., from the 2nd reference, "The use of the standard textbook method, x/n +/- 1.96 square root of [(x/n)(1-x/n)/n], or its continuity corrected version, is strongly discouraged".
Your textbook uses the "exact" binomial method (aka Clopper-Pearson), which is based on binomial distribution, because the distribution of your data exactly follows a binomial.
You are using a normal approximation to the binomial (i.e. it approximates a discrete distribution with a continuous one, and approximates a binomial shape with a gaussian). Now, that works reasonably well in many instances, but certainly not always; and you data is one such case where the approximation becomes a bit too approximate (low total sample size, observed probability far "enough" from .5). Many more normal approximations exist, which work better that Wald, but still not universally better than the exact binomial (e.g. Agresti-Coul, Wilsdon score, etc.).
One more detail; the Wald test you ran was single tailed; a 2-tailed test (such as the one used by the textbook) would give $p=0.03142$, fwiw.
So, let's see what some of the "other normal approximations" would give, for 2-tailed tests.\

Wald: $p=.03142$
Agresti-Coul: $p=0.04052$
Wilson score: $p=0.03142$

And compare this to the exact binomial

Clopper-Pearson: $p=0.05556$
Blaker's exact: $p=0.05565$ (a "new. improved" version of Clopper-Pearson)

So which one to believe? In your specific case (only 15 observations, with an observed proportion of almost .75, and a test against a proportion of .9), I would believe the "exact" CI's. This is the PMF for $B(15,.9)$; sorry, but this does not look normal...

Note that if instead your data had been 110 cured out of 150, all tests would have given $p=0.00000$. And below is the PMF for $B(150,.9)$; not normal either, but much closer, and probably good enough.

Also, in the first case, the observed proportion could only take 1 of 16 possible values (~6% discontinuities; not very continuous). In the 2nd case, the observed proportion can take any of 151 possible values (.7% discontinuities; much better).\
Now, once upon a time, before computers and statistical software (when dinosaurs roamed the cubicles), computations based on the binomial distribution, by hand or even calculators, were daunting (to say the least), particularly for large sample sizes, because it required computing factorials. So it was pragmatic to try normal approximations (with complete and easy z tables). But today?
